# How to indicate that method is a part of interface with PHPDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

How to indicate that method is a part of interface with PHPDoc?

For example:

```php
/**
 * @implements BarInterface
 */
class Foo implements BarInterface
{
    /**
     * @thisMethodIsHereBecauseItIsAPartOf("BarInterface")
     */
    public function doBar()
    {
    }
}
```

Is there anything appropriate to replace `@thisMethodIsHereBecauseItIsAPartOf("BarInterface")` with?

Comment: There isn't anything built-in, but why would you need to do that? This information can be produced by static analysis of the code, so why provide it manually instead?

Comment: I use `@see BarInterface::doBar();`

Comment: @Jon I want to see something this information at first glance in any text editor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How to indicate that method is a part of interface with PHPDoc?

You do not need to document that, because you use `implements BarInterface` and a source-code documentation system normally handles these automatically.

However you can also use `@inherit(doc)`:

```
/**
 * @implements BarInterface
 */
class Foo implements BarInterface
{
    /**
     * @inherit
     * {@inherit}
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function doBar()
    {
    }
}
```

About your `@implements BarInterface` on top, this is *superfluous*, because it's already written in the class definition. As comments count as code, and as you should not write *superfluous code*, I suggest you to remove it.