# Where to write phpDoc? Interface or class

Tags: phpdoc

Where should I write phpDoc? Upon interface in interface file or upon class that implements the interface?
I am a bit sad that I can't write return types and types of params before param in methods. In PHP I have to do that in phpDoc, but where should I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the docblock in the interface. If there is something specific for some class, you could write docblock for it.

You can specify argument types, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Great! It's a pitty that type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. Also would be fine to define return types just like in java. Thanks for satisfying answer.

Comment: More discussion on this is here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036058/phpdoc-for-interface-and-class-implementing-interface-difference/25041475#25041475