# Best practice for PHP interfaces: should I document only the interface?

Tags: php

I'm trying to standardize documentation for PHP interfaces.  Is the best practice to maintain the method header only in the interface?  For example, for this interface:

```
interface FooInterface {

    /** 
     * This will test the system in some special way
     * @param string $sName
     * @param integer $iCount
     * @return void
     */
    public function testMe ($sName, $iCount);
}
```

I would skip the method header documentation in the implementation:

```
class Foo implements FooInterface {

    /**
     * @see FooInterface::testMe
     */
    public function testMe ($sName, $iCount) {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

Or is it better to document the parameters in both the interface and implementation? E.g.

```
class Foo implements FooInterface {

    /**
     * @see FooInterface::testMe
     * @param string $sName
     * @param integer $iCount
     * @return void
     */
    public function testMe ($sName, $iCount) {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

Normally I prefer to minimize duplication and maintenance, but perhaps there are good reasons to store the header documentation for parameters and return values in both places?

Comment: I generally think of it as, "If something goes wrong and some one else needs to read through my code, do I want them diving through files and folders for documentation references?" so for medium projects with a few folders I duplicate documentation, but for large projects I keep external documentation.

Comment: Those examples are not really worthwhile documentation to begin with. One-liners, `@inheritDoc` and omission don't make that much of a difference. (Except to satisfy pro-forma style guides.)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036058/phpdoc-for-interface-and-class-implementing-interface-difference/25041475

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [phpDocumentor](http://phpdoc.org), the `@inheritdoc` annotation is a good idea, as already suggested by @Scalable. This (fixed) [bug tracker issue](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/389) confirms that the `@inheritdoc` annotations also works for implemented interfaces.

---

To expand on that a little bit:

Usually, a method comment should describe **what a method does**[1]. Typically, all implementations of a method defined by an interface should do the same (and only differ in their implementation). This in mind, I'd recomment the following:

1. use the method comment in the *interface* definition to describe what the method is supposed to do:

   ```
   interface UserRepository {
       /**
        * Returns all existing users (duh! usually, you'd omit a comment 
        * like this because the method signature is already self-explanatory).
        *
        * @return User[]
        */
       public function findAllUsers();
   }
   ```
2. use the `@inheritdoc` annotation in method comment in the *implementing classes* and provide additional implementation-specific details when necessary:

   ```
   class RemoteUserRepository implements UserRepository{
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        *
        * This is achieved by performing a SOAP call to Service XYZ.
        * For performance reasons, results will be cached for 24 hours.
        * Blah, blah, blah.
        */
       public function findAllUsers() {
           // here be dragons
       }
   }
   ```

---

1. On a side note: If you need to document *how* your method does what it does, it's maybe too complex and should be broken down into smaller units.

Comment: I'm sorry that you are having to use SOAP---even in your examples :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that documenting the interface should be good enough because the methods implementations should do what the interface are telling them to do. In PHP you cannot force a method's return value so If two implementations of the same method return different values, then you should override the interface documentation in the implementation that differs from it.

Comment: "In PHP you cannot force a method's return value": With PHP7, it's possible. See [return types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration), [nullable types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types) and [void functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.void-functions).

Answer (score 2):

I think using:

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
```

whenever possible should be adopted. I dont know this works as good for interfaces as it does for class inheritance.